# Unwinding list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

```
unwindHead([E|Es], F) :- unwinded(E); unwindHead(E, E). 
unwinded(L) :- \+ is_list(L).  

?-  unwindHead([[1]], X).
```

Above return true but it doesn't returns `X`. Why?

Comment: It doesn't unify `X` with anything because your second argument to `unwindHead` is *singleton* (you did see the warning message, right?). That means you have a variable you only use in one place and is therefore unified with a value never used, or is never unified with a value.

Comment: ok, how to improve it? I tried to use it at rightside but the result is same :(

Comment: Honestly, I'm not exactly sure what you want this predicate to do in general.

Comment: For example:
unwindHead([[1,5,4], 2,9]]) should return 1.
unwindHead([[[[[0]]]]]) should return 0. So it should unwrap the most first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is very close, and I think you're just getting twisted up in the Prolog. You just need to break it down logically first, then look at the Prolog. Correctly, you're thinking in terms of the case whether the first element in the list is itself a list. Writing out what the rules might look like:

1. If we "unwind" `[E|_]` and `E` is not a list, then we get `E`.
2. If we "unwind" `[E|_]` and `E` is a list, then we (recursively) "unwind" `E` to get the result.

Which would look like:

```
unwind_head([E|_], E) :- \+ is_list(E).
unwind_head([E|_], F) :- is_list(E), unwind_head(E, F).
```

You can also use the Prolog "if-else" construct for this:

```
unwind_head([E|_], F) :-
    (   is_list(E)
    ->  unwind_head(E, F)
    ;   F = E
    ).
```

Note that we never care what the tail of the list is, so we can use `_`.

Comment: Thanks :).
1. Is it possible to print searching tree in Prolog?
2. Is it possible to debug step by step?
3. Every if can be replaced with construction described by the first example in your answer, am I right?

Comment: @Gilgamesz You can use `trace` to debug step by step. It will not, however, print a search tree. You need to do that by hand.